# How can I set a specific position to array elements with the map function and a given index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm working with a react site that shows dynamic data from a server. Here's the content from the parent.

```
  axiosFunc = () => {

  axios.get('https://api.warframestat.us/pc').then(results => {
  this.setState({
    fissures: results.data.fissures
  });

  console.log(this.state.fissures)

      setTimeout(this.axiosFunc,1000 * 60);
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.axiosFunc();
  }
```

Now when I use the map function in the child element, the data pops out...

```
  render() {
return(
  <main>
    <header>{this.props.whichEvent.toUpperCase()}</header>
    {
      this.props.theData.map(
        fissure => {
          return (
            <section key={fissure.id}>
              <h1>{fissure.missionType} // {fissure.node}</h1>
              <figure className="leftfigure">
                <img src={require(`../icons/${fissure.tier}.svg`)} alt=""/>
                <figcaption></figcaption>
              </figure>
              <figure>
                <figcaption></figcaption>
              </figure>
            </section>
          )
        }
      )
    }
  </main>
)
}
```

But it comes out in whichever order the server passes the objects to me. I want to sort them based off of the fissure.tierNum value in each object. The number is from 1 to 4 depending on the object. As I make the elements with map, how do I take that number and sort the elements based off of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add sort function before your map function to sort by key you want like so

```
this.props.theData.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.tierNum < b.tierNum) {
    return -1;
  }
  else return 1;
}).map(...)
```

You can learn more about sort function at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks. The main issue is that I didn't know how to set up the sort function here, since I've never had to sort and map at the same time.